# Debugging NodeJS with Eclipse nodeclipse issues

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I can debug nodejs with the nodeclipse plugin. The only issue I have is the hover over during single stepping does not show complete properties list. Is this something I can fix?

Also can someone create add nodeclipse tag line please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All project properties are shown as a tree in Variables View, you can also use Expression View. This is standard Eclipse experience.